# euler project 3 ruby> why does this solution work?

Tags: ruby, arrays, syntax

```
def large_prime(n)
  return [] if n==1 
  factor = (2..n).find {|x| n % x == 0}
  [factor] + large_prime(n/factor)
end
```

I got this solution from somewhere else.  I don't understand the 4th line of code where  large_prime is called recursively and appended onto factor.
When I change the first line "return []" and leave out the '[]' after the return, I get an error message for on line 4, that says '+':no implicit conversion of nil into Array.
So why does this code work? Thanks

P.S. I'm obviously a noob and everything is very new to me.

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd line finds the first divisor of `n` between `2` and `n`. This line itself does not involve recursion.

I don't really get the code you modified, but it seems to return `nil` in some case, while the original method always return an Array.

Comment: Sorry i meant the 4th line of code is where the recursion occurs. And yes.  I dont understand how it is able to return an array.  It looks like its just adding [factor] with large_prime(n/factor). It looks like return [ ] has something to do with it.  I just don't get how it works

Comment: @user3474118 if the method execution is not ended by an earlier `return` statement, the last expression (`[factor] + large_prime(n/factor)` in this case) is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You must return an empty array when passed 1 to terminate the recursion. Any positive argument other than one will result in another call to `large_prime`, but an argument of 1 results in `large_prime` simply returning an empty array.

At each level of recursion, the program adds an array with the single factor it found to an array consisting of all factors found for the value `n/factor`. When the last factor (other than 1) is found, the final call to `large_prime` is made with an argument of 1, `large_prime` returns an empty array which is then added to the array containing the last factor, giving an array containing just the last factor. This array is then returned and you have 
`[next-to-last-factor] + [last-factor]`, giving a return array of `[next-to-last-factor, last-factor]` which is added to `[next-to-next-to-last-factor]` giving `[next-to-next-to-last-factor, next-to-last-factor, last-factor]`. This is then added to an array `[next-to-next-to-next-to-last-factor]`, giving... lather, rinse, repeat until we reach the largest factor and add it in.

You must return an empty array because you can't add `nil` to an array in Ruby.

Comment: Whats actually happening on the third line factor = (2..n).find {|x| n % x == 0}?  I get that the find method stops at the time it meets the condition, but how does that give the prime factors? Lets say I use the argument 56.  The prime factors are [2,2,2,7]  somehow it goes from 2 to 7.  Shouldn't it also stop at 4? Since 56%4 ==0.

Comment: The series never gets to 4 since any possible N with N%4 == 0 will have N%2 == 0.